# cups unable to communicate with avahi-daemon when running as a service

Tags: raspbian, cups, avahi

I'm finishing setting up my Raspberry Pi in a read-only mode and cups service seems to be the last thing that is causing me issues.

As cups writes the config to /etc, I decided to mount /etc/cups as an overlay system:

```
$ mount
...
overlay on /etc/cups type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/etc/cups_org,upperdir=/etc/cups_rw/upper,workdir=/etc/cups_rw/work)
...
```

The cups service starts successfully, I'm able to access the localhost:631 page, however going to /admin subpage results in "Internal server error" and the /printer subpage shows: Unable to get printer list: Bad file descriptor.

During startup of the service I see in the log:

```
E [03/Sep/2016:17:17:13 +0200] Unable to communicate with avahi-daemon: Daemon not running
```

while the avahi daemon is active and running

When accessing the /admin subpage the log shows:

```
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [CGI] Started /usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi (PID 5367)
I [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [Client 13] Started "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi" (pid=5367)
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [Client 13] file=14
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [Client 13] Waiting for CGI data.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] Report: clients=1
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] Report: jobs=0
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] Report: jobs-active=0
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] Report: printers=1
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] Report: stringpool-string-count=654
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] Report: stringpool-alloc-bytes=6392
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] Report: stringpool-total-bytes=11720
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [CGI] admin.cgi started...
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
E [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [CGI] Unable to connect to cupsd: Bad file descriptor
E [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [CGI] Unable to connect to cupsd: Bad file descriptor
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [CGI] cupsServer()="/var/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [CGI] ippPort()=631
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [CGI] cupsEncryption()=0
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] [Client 13] CGI data ready to be sent.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:22:39 +0200] PID 5367 (/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi) stopped with status 1.
```

However, when I stop the service, and run the program manually:

```
/usr/sbin/cupsd -f
```

the problem does not occur at all. The log shows:

```
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:33 +0200] Avahi server connection now available, registering printers for Bonjour broadcasting.
```

And I'm able to access /admin (and all the other subpages):

```
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [CGI] Started /usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi (PID 6269)
I [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [Client 17] Started "/usr/lib/cups/cgi-bin/admin.cgi" (pid=6269)
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [Client 17] file=18
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [Client 17] Waiting for CGI data.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [CGI] admin.cgi started...
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [Client 19] Accepted from localhost (Domain)
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [Client 19] Waiting for request.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [CGI] http=0x554e9db8
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: SECTION="admin"
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [CGI] cgiSetVariable: REFRESH_PAGE=""
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] cupsd is not idle any more, canceling shutdown.
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [CGI] org.cups.sid cookie is "72b5efbcd72416115613b87b329ce911"
D [03/Sep/2016:18:25:36 +0200] [CGI] No form data, showing main menu...
```

Any hints on what can be the reason of this behavior and how to solve the issue (change the config in cups.service file?) or at least to move this troubleshooting further?

Comment: There might be a mount propagation problem with the overlay filesystem when it is mixed in with systemd's use of a mount namespace. You might try commenting out the `PrivateTmp` line in the cups Unit to see if it helps, and/or do `mount --make-shared /etc/cups`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and what helped me is that I had edited the file: `/usr/lib/systemd/system/org.cups.cupsd.service`

```ini
[Unit]
Description=CUPS Scheduler
Documentation=man:cupsd(8)
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cupsd -f

[Install]
Also=org.cups.cupsd.socket org.cups.cupsd.path
WantedBy=printer.target
```

And restarted the service as `root` or with `sudo`:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart org.cups.cupsd
```